# Python list input error

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

```
grid = []
for _ in range(3):
    grid.append(raw_input().split())
```

**Input:**

```
000
000
000
```

**Output**:
`[['000'], ['000'], ['000']]`.

How do I change my code to get the output?

`[['0','0','0'], ['0','0','0'],['0','0','0']]`

Comment: You can also try to change the input format as well, try `0 0 0` and the above code will work as expected.

Comment: it seems your code doesn't have this output:`[['000'], ['000'], ['000']]`, when I run your code, entering 9 0s, the output seems to be this: `[['000000000']]`

Answer (score 10):

You have:

```
"000".split() == ["000"]
```

You want:

```
list("000") == ["0", "0", "0"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not putting a space between each 0's so you don't split anything,  just call list on the raw_input:

```
grid = [list(raw_input())]
for _ in range(3):
    grid.append(list(raw_input()))
```

You can also use a list comp:

```
 grid = [list(raw_input()) for _ in range(3)]
```

If you wanted to split you would need to enter `0 0 0` with spaces between.

```
In [1]: "0 0 0".split()
Out[1]: ['0', '0', '0']
```

Trying to split `"000"` returns  `['000']` because there is no delimiter to split on, no whitespace etc..